# How to send data back to previous sceen when using navigation.goBack()?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've got screen 1 from which I navigate to screen 2 using:

```
navigation.navigate('Screen2')
```

From this screen, I would like to go to the previous one, which simple:

```
navigation.goBack()
```

However I'm wondering how can I pass some data back to Screen1? Something like wouldn't work `navigation.goBack({ myData: 'something' })` so I'm wondering what is the recommended way to do this in general?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can solve it with 2 ways :

**1 : Using navigation method**

Pass a method when you are calling that screen through navigation :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
  onGoBack: this.refresh,
});

refresh=(data)=> {

}
```

and when you press back, pass data like

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.onGoBack('123');
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

**2 : Using redux store**

If you are using redux in your application, just update redux store whenever user presses back button, and get store value in previous screen.

Comment: i have a similar question, i can navigate from Screen1 to Screen2 passing all the params as well, in Screen2 i updated one of the params passed and now i want to update it in Screen1 as well but not navigate to Screen1. Is that possible?

Comment: This is not recommended since the library will warn you that passing in functions as parameters can be problematic since it can't be serialized

Answer (score 10):

You can pass a callback (onSelect) like this:

SCREEN 1

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button, Text, View } from "react-native";

class Screen1 extends React.Component {
  state = { selected: false };

  onSelect = data => {
    this.setState(data);
  };

  onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigate("Screen2", { onSelect: this.onSelect });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{this.state.selected ? "Selected" : "Not Selected"}</Text>
        <Button title="Next" onPress={this.onPress} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

SCREEN 2

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-native";

class Screen2 extends React.Component {
  goBack() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    navigation.goBack();
    navigation.state.params.onSelect({ selected: true });
  }

  render() {
    return <Button title="back" onPress={this.goBack} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the navigation method
Pass a method when you are calling that screen through navigation :

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {
  onGoBack: this.refresh,
});

refresh=(data)=> {
   console.log(data)
}
```

and when you press back, pass data like

```js
this.props.route.params.onGoBack('123');
this.props.navigation.goBack();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// PreviousScreen.js
const PreviousScreen = () => {
  const handleData = (data) => {
    // Handle the received data here
    console.log('Received data:', data);
  };

  // Navigate to the next screen and pass the callback function as a parameter
  const goToNextScreen = () => {
    navigation.navigate('NextScreen', { callback: handleData });
  };

  // ...
};/
// NextScreen.js
const NextScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  // Retrieve the callback function from the navigation parameters
  const callback = route.params?.callback;

  // Call the callback function with the data you want to send back
  const sendDataToPreviousScreen = () => {
    const data = 'Hello from NextScreen!';
    callback && callback(data); // Make sure the callback exists before calling it
    navigation.goBack();
  };

  // ...
};
```

Answer (score -1):

if you're using v2 or newer, another possibility is using the `navigate` function, providing `key` / `routeName` of the route you're going back to and the `params`. docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-actions.html#navigate

Answer (score -2):

yes goback work for going previous screen to ...and show our data call from api ...goBack()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).