# Passing data along with navigation to the parent screen in React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create a hybrid app in the **react-native** platform. We have two pages in here. The first page is a tabbed page and the other one is a detailed page. I want to pass some data to the parent page from the second page when the back arrow in the header portion is clicked(*i.e; when the navigation is happening*), and want to display it on the first page.

I have succeeded in passing data to the child page from the parent page and that data is being used on the second page. But the same can't be done vice-versa.

This is what I have tried.

**Parent page**

```js
class Menu extends Component {   

   refresh=(data)=> {
      alert(data);   } }

   render() {
     return (
       <View>
      
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail',{
            onGoBack: this.refresh,
          }); 
         }}> 
       </View>);
  }
```

**In the child page**

```js
static navigationOptions= ({ navigation }) => {
    //const {state} = navigation;
    return {
        
        headerTitle: (
            <View>
                <Image source={require('../images/assets/menuscreenlogo.png')}/>
            </View>
        ),
        headerLeft: (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.state.params.onGoBack('123');
            this.props.navigation.goBack();}} >
            
                <Image source={require('../images/assets/dinnerscreen-backarrow.png')}  />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
        headerRight: (
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Image  source={require('../images/assets/dinnerscreen-basket.png')} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      };
};
```

Can anyone help me out to do the same?

Comment: Are you using `react-navigation`? or anything else?

Comment: I am using react-navigation

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52552935/3134215)

Comment: I have tried it before. **undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this4.props.navigation')** is the error that i am getting when navigating back to the parent screen

Comment: `<TouchableOpacity style={{margin:5}} onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetail',{
                productId:item.id,
                onGoBack: this.refresh,
                //returnData: this.returnData.bind(this),
              });
            }}>`     **parent page.**                     
 `refresh=(data)=> {
    alert(data);
  }`

Comment: // Second Page                                                                       `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.state.params.onGoBack('123');
                this.props.navigation.goBack();}} >`

Comment: Please post code in question, with proper format so it will be easy for others to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use `this.props.navigation` in child page as you are already getting `navigation` object there, so it should be

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {navigation.state.params.onGoBack('123');
        navigation.goBack();}} >
```

Comment: What if, i need the data from the child page to be accessed in another tab of the parent page?

Comment: You can use redux for that, it will be easy

Comment: is there any solution using react-navigation?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Okay Ravi. Thank you for your time